# How to call oracle function using Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, oracle, mono

Working with Mono I needed to call a function in an oracle database. The function has two input parameters and one output parameter.

At first I tested with .Net runtime. The following pretty simple code did the job:

```
var dbcon = new OracleConnection("my connection string");
dbcon.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "my_pkg.my_func";

OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("ReturnValue", OracleType.Number);
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

p = new OracleParameter("p_in1", OracleType.VarChar);
p.Size = 5;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p.Value = p1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

p = new OracleParameter("p_in2", OracleType.VarChar);
p.Size = 20;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p.Value = p2;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

p = new OracleParameter("p_out", OracleType.VarChar);
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
p.Size = 512;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);    

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

return cmd.Parameters["p_out"].Value.ToString();
```

However, as the target OS is Linux, I changed the runtime (*Utilities=>Options=>.Net Runtimes*) to Mono (ver. 2.10.9). The first issue I experienced then was the bug mentioned in

1. [Bug 10164 - System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.SetOracleType throws System.NullReferenceException](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10164)
2. [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.SetOracleType() bug?](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/System-Data-OracleClient-OracleParameter-SetOracleType-bug-td3855825.html)

As far as I understand the only way out is to set `OracleParameter.Value` before `OracleParameter.OracleType`, even for output parameters... So the code was changed to

```
p = new OracleParameter();
p.ParameterName = "p_in1";
p.Size = 5;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;    
p.Value = code.ToString ();                
p.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
```

The `NullReferenceException` disappeared, but another arrised:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'my_func'
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

As it is said in [Mono - Oracle: Current Status for System.Data.OracleClient](http://www.mono-project.com/Oracle) :

> ```
> Input/Output and Return parameters have not been tested.
> ```

is `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` even supported?

Or why does it work with the .Net runtime and does not with Mono?

Comment: I know it is a very old question, but have you managed to make it work? I have the same problem here. Thanks

Comment: @EdgarRochaCarvalho Unforunately no. I had to give up the idea to use Mono for this. As far as I remember there were few more problems with Mono, I couldn't solve. So I used Java instead.

Comment: It worked fine with stored procedure and out parameter, so I created a sp that call a function and assign it's return value to out parameter of the stored procedure. I can't give up of mono so I will use this workaround. Thanks!